# If $X$ and $Y$ are independent $\implies$ $E(X|Y)=E(X)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

---

Exercices :

Let $X$ et $Y$ be a random variables  integrable such that $XY$ also integrable .
Prove that :

---

> if $X$ and $Y$ are independent  $\implies$ $E(X|Y)=E(X)$
> $\implies~~~E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$

My teacher was give a note ( remark )

- start by using the indicator function i.e
  $$X=\mathbb{1_{A}}~~~,~~~Y=\mathbb{1_{B}}$$
  I know that  :
  $$E(\mathbb{1_{A}|B)}=\mathbb{P}(A|B)$$
  But I don't have I idea to complete!!
  Can you help me!

---

This is home work!!

Comment: When starting a proof, something that always helps me is to write out the definitions of the terms involved: what definitions are you using for $E(X|Y)$ and $E(XY)$?

Comment: Start from your professor's hint.  What else is P(A|B) equal to?  What is it equal to when A and B are independent?  What else can you observe?

Comment: @nomen please can you drop à solution to understand!!

Answer (score 1):

$E(X \mid Y) = E(X)$ means that for every $A \subset \mathbb{R}$, $E(1_{A}(Y)X)= E(1_{A}(Y)E(X)) = E(1_A(Y))E(X)$. To prove this, we only need to show if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $E(XY) = E(X)E(Y)$. This is a consequence of Fubini's theorem and the fact that $X$ and $Y$ are independent if and only if $P_{(X, Y)} = P_X \times P_Y$.